# MaxInternalRetryCountReached - The specified task has reached maximum internal retry count

Tags: azure-batch

Would you please explain when this task scheduling error will happen?

**MaxInternalRetryCountReached - The specified task has reached maximum internal retry count**   MSDN link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/batch-status-and-error-codes).

The background is that I see this error sometimes, for jobs with tasks whose RetryCount = 1.  When this error is seen, the retry count is 1 (which means it was retried).  However the task returned Exit Code of 0 and it appeared to have done its job successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal retries for tasks can happen if there are transient issues when a task is scheduled to a compute node (i.e., an Azure Storage error occurs) or if the node cannot schedule the task on the node due to some issue (i.e., preparing the task's directory failed).

The internal retry count is a separate counter from that of the task's normal retry count which is triggered from retries occurring normally, e.g., a retry as a result of a non-successful exit code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is there a way to get details of the cause of such an error instance?  It happens randomly, so if the details can be known, we might be able to prevent it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is currently no way to query why an internal retry was triggered. You can raise an Azure support ticket with your region, account, pool, job, task and approximate time of when the task completed and ask for why an internal retry occurred. It will be valuable if the compute node for which the task ran on is still active.